# Wrong Bitmap Width and Height with Android 4 (ICS)

Tags: android, bitmap, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

On Android 2.2 and 2.3 Devices

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_original_drawable);
```

generates a bitmap, that has exactly the same size than it's source. On my Galaxy Nexus with Android 4 (ICS) the generated bitmap is always too big. It's scaled even though it should not be.

That's a big problem. Did anyone experience the same?

Comment: do you have the Source File put in all 3 folders for low, medium and high pixel density?

Comment: No I only have one version of them in drawable-hdpi.

Comment: copypaste it in the other ones, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact same problem experienced and only on ICS.

My workaround was to get the raw stream and convert it to BitMapDrawable

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(largePhotoDrawableId)
BitmapDrawable photo= null;
photo= new BitmapDrawable(resources,inputStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

put source file in "res/drawable-xhdpi/"  folder or "res/drawable-sw720dp/"  folder

for more help read this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

happy coding

Comment: right direction ... but I would have to create graphics for all resolutions which would would significantly increase the size of my app.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty late reply, but since I had the same issue and have solved it I wanted to let you know.
The solution to this problem is to either put all your resources in corresponding folders, like drawable-xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi... so on.

If you want to use the same resources for all screen densities, put them in drawable-nodpi. This way all devices will use the resource as is.

If you keep them in plain drawable, it will be the default which is mdpi, and any devices with higher dpi, will enlarge the resource to fit their screen.

hope this helps ;)